# Birt not being able to find available fields Mongodb datasource dataset

Tags: mongodb, eclipse, birt

I'm trying to connect a mongodb database to Birt and create a dataset. But after i connect (ping get succeeded) the database and trying to set up the dataset by specifying a collection name but following error comes

```
Unable to find available fields. Invalid collection name clinic.
```

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 1):

Seems its an issue with the mongodb-java driver.

Open the Eclipse IDE and navigate to the plugins dir, delete the `org.eclipse.orbit.mongodb_2.10.1.v20130422-1135.jar` file, and add the `mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.jar` there.